# Using Alias matches domain level object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a domain level object called Task.

I want to use `Task.Factory.StartNew(()` in my Domain Layer to kick off a method in the background.

However it keeps picking up Task as my Domain Level object rather than the System.Threading Task.

Even with the below defined at the top of my class:

```
using Task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;

namespace My.Domain
```

I can do the below where I call my method I want to run in the background:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyBackgroundMethod());
```

and it works as expected but I was just wondering am I missing something simple that would mean I can get rid of fully qualifying the threading Task where I am using it

Comment: You could give it an alias other than task, eg. `using SystemTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
using SystemTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task;
```

so alias wouldn't collide with your domain type?

Comment: had just update the code to do that and called it FrameworkTask - was just wondering was there any other way around this